# How to Prepopulate Room database correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to build a simple text-based adventure game. I have a database of quests and I'm trying to get an access to it, but I dont understand how to do it correctly, can someone help me?

here is my Dao:

```
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM quests")
    fun readAll(): Flow<List<QuestEntity>>

    @Query("SELECT story FROM quests WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getStoryById(id: Int): String
}
```

DataBase:

```
@Database(entities = [QuestEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class DataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): Dao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DataBase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): DataBase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE =
                        Room.databaseBuilder(context, DataBase::class.java, "quests")
                            .createFromAsset("quests.db")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "quests")
data class QuestEntity (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    val story: String,
    val choice1: String,
    val choice2: String,
    val next1: Int,
    val next2: Int

    )
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(database: DataBase): ViewModel() {

    val dao = database.getDao()
    var allQuests: LiveData<List<QuestEntity>> = dao.readAll().asLiveData()
    
    fun getStoryById(storyID: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        dao.getStoryById(storyID)
    }
    

    class MainViewModelFactory(val database: DataBase): ViewModelProvider.Factory{
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)){
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MainViewModel(database) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModelClass")
        }

    }

}
```

MainApp:

```
class MainApp: Application() {
    val database by lazy{ DataBase.getDatabase(this)}
}
```

And finaly MainActivity there I only tried to get access to one of the fields in quests.db (story) and displaing that into an activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var bindingClass: ActivityMainBinding
    
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels{
        MainViewModel.MainViewModelFactory((applicationContext as MainApp).database)
    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)

        bindingClass.textStory.text = viewModel.getStoryById(1).toString() // its not getting a "story" from database, instead writes: "StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@6c601d9"

    }
}
```

I'm just trying to learn kotlin so I don't know how to build this correctly

Comment: how did you prepopulate the data inside database? there is no insert query in your Dao.

Comment: @zaid OP is using `createFromAsset()`

Comment: How did you create `quests.db`? You should grab the empty database from your app's files folder and prepopulate *that* file. Don't create a new (empty) database manually, Room generally doesn't like that.

Comment: @Remc4 I created quests.db with DB Browser(SQL Lite), filled it with values and placed it in "assets"

Comment: Does your code crash? Or is the database just empty?

Comment: @Remc4 database is not empty, the app just won't start

Comment: Please edit your question with the stack trace of the crash

Comment: @Remc4 there is no trace of the crash, android studio writes that "launch succeeded", but the app just won't open on an emulator of a phone - just black blink and nothing

Comment: This is weird. Is there also nothing in LogCat? If you're on Windows, press `Alt+F6` to open it. I still suspect the problem is that you've created the db file from scratch, instead of pulling an empty db from the phone and filling it with data. I suspect the app then crashes with `Room cannot verify the data integrity`, because Room is *very* strict about that.

Comment: @Remc4 i added coroutine, so the app is not crushing now, but instead of the "story" in database it wrote: "StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@6c601d9" and also LogCat writes "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."

Comment: It seems like you're using coroutines wrong. I think you're missing a suspend keyword somewhere. Can you edit your question with the new code?

Comment: @Remc4 already done

Answer (score 1):

you has a wrong function:

```
fun getStoryById(storyID: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    dao.getStoryById(storyID)
}
```

Be cause `viewModelScope.launch{ your code }` return Job but you want to return your data class from DB. To get it you can get returned value and put it to LiveData like this ->
Your ViewModel class:

```
class MainViewModel(database: DataBase): ViewModel() {

val dao = database.getDao()
var allQuests: LiveData<List<QuestEntity>> = dao.readAll().asLiveData()
var storyById = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun getStoryById(storyID: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    storyById.postValue(dao.getStoryById(storyID))
}


class MainViewModelFactory(val database: DataBase): ViewModelProvider.Factory{
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)){
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MainViewModel(database) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModelClass")
    }
}
```

Your Activity where you can get returned value from DB:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var bindingClass: ActivityMainBinding

val database by lazy{ DataBase.getDatabase(this)

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels <MainViewModel> {
        MainViewModel.MainViewModelFactory(database)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)

        viewModel.storyById.observe(this) { story ->
            bindingClass.textStory.text = story
        }
        viewModel.getStoryById(1)

    }
}
```